# Handling web.config files - alternative to ConfigurationManager

Tags: asp.net, web-config

The other day I came across an alternative way of accessing web.config configuration in some article. It allowed to:

- provide path to web.config file
- modify web.config configuration at runtime like:

  `config.MySetting = "new value";`
- load web.config from another web application in the same IIS (I'm not sure about it)
- work with configuration using class instance instead of static ConfigurationManager class

But that solution slipped my mind :/ I remember that the article was titled (something like this): Way of using application configuration in web applications.

Could somebody came across that solution and could refresh my memory with a link ? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was it [`System.Configuration.Configuration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx)?

Call `WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration` with a file name to get a `Configuration` instance, which has its own `AppSettings` collection.